# Why view.frame.width returns zero?

Tags: ios, swift

I created stackView and added three labels to it. Also I put these constraints

```
let nameLabel = UILabel()
//set .text, .mode and other for nameLabel
let ellipsisLabel = UILabel()
//set .text, .mode and other for ellipsisLabel
let amountAndMeasureLabel = UILabel()
//set .text, .mode and other for amountAndMeasureLabel

for label in [nameLabel, ellipsisLabel, amountAndMeasureLabel] {
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
            }
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ellipsisLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                nameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: nameLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width),
                amountAndMeasureLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ellipsisLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                amountAndMeasureLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
                amountAndMeasureLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: amountAndMeasureLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width)
            ])

nameLabel.frame.width // 0
ellipsisLabel.frame.width // 0
amountAndMeasureLabel.frame.width // 0
```

I will demonstrate the situation on .xib for better understanding (I don't use this .xib)

[image]

But when I tried to get their .frame.width I got zeros.

Comment: where you are setting all this ?

Comment: @jawadAli over the insert cycle. You can see, I updated

Comment: code is in didload ? willAppear ? awake from nib ?

Comment: i think you are also getting error in console about constraints break ... check them

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/vladimir-d/BoxView container instead of UIStackView for such layouts. Less boilerplate code, and clearer layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just activating constraints doesn't cause a view to layout. If you need `stackView` to immediately layout its subviews, you need to tell it to:

```
stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Otherwise the system will automatically collect and apply all layout updates together the next time it's needed. Since forcing a layout may lead to unnecessary computations (if something later in the draw cycle changes the layout), you should generally avoid calling `.layoutIfNeeded()` unless you really need it. But it's fully supported if you do.

There is also `.setNeedsLayout()`, which tells the system that a view needs layout during the next draw cycle. You should use this if something changes layout in a way that the system won't notice. You generally don't need this if your changes are through UIKit itself. UIStackView knows that it needs layout after you call `.addArrangedSubview`. But if you change some piece of data that your layout relies on, you may need to tell UIKit.